# How do I run Spring Boot Thymeleaf along with Vue.js?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm working on a small project that has already used Thymeleaf to render the view. But now I want a section of the pages to integrate Vue.js.
I can open 2 applications on separate ports e.g. 8080 and 8081 but I want to know how to have an HTML file with both Thymeleaf and Vue.js (is that even possible) and if there's a way to run both of them on the same port.

All of the articles I find use @RestController to make the Spring project a Rest API, but I use @Controller with a view tho.

Thank you all

Comment: If you still on that, i did a small blog post combining pettite-vue and thymeleaf: https://sombriks.com/blog/0048-progressive-vue-js-on-ssr-java/

Answer (score 1):

Vue.js is Progressive.

You can add it to your project in any degree of integration.

Since tymeleaf is processed in backend, a full featured vue project delivers bundled version of files already rendered, so they concurr at this point.

A good silver lining is to add it as a regular javascipt dependecy, managed by [webjars](https://www.webjars.org/), then consume it in thymeleaf templates.

By doing that, you **give up on single file components, dev server and hot module replacement during development**, but you still able to create vue instances and use reactivity on thymeleaf-rendered pages.

See here more details about how to use vue as [standalone script](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/ways-of-using-vue.html#standalone-script).

#### update

I wrote a [small blog post](https://sombriks.com/blog/0048-progressive-vue-js-on-ssr-java/) detailing more on how one could add some modern vue capabilities into a already running fine java web project.